# Why std::filesystem does not have overloads for conversion from and to POSIX permissions?

Tags: c++, permissions, stl, c++17, std-filesystem

I have a file with paths and permissions in POSIX octal notation. The file paths must exist and permissions are checked as per the manifest file. If mismatch, set new filesystem permissions as per manifest. Is there an easy conversion between `std::filesystem::perms` and POSIX permissions?

As checked [`std::filesystem::permissions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions) has no integral type overload. The values in `perms` are non sequential.

I looked into [BitmaskType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BitmaskType) named requirement, `std::to_underlying` and `std::underlying_type`.

The current workaround initializes `std::array<std::filesystem::perms, 12>` manually with all possible individual (single bit) permissions, but is dependent on the element positions and if upstream makes changes to the `perms` `enum class`, the code will break.

Iterating over the array works by setting corresponding bits in `std::bitset<12>`, checking each bit and casting the `bitset` to an unsigned integral type.

This is necessary since `std::filesystem::perms` is an `enum class` and unable to iterate over.

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, the standard library rarely provides platform - specific APIs

Comment: The size of the `array` and `bitset` is 12. I should mention that `size_t POSIX_PERMS_SIZE=12;`.

Comment: it is highly improbable, that `upstream makes changes to the perms enum class` as this is a structure that is used by trillions of systems since decades. Be sure, that quite a lot will complain if a change to this enum gets announced :-)